# parsing data between forms to datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, parsing

i have a main form name fmMain

[image]

black mark is show browse file path to datagridview

and red mark is show form to datagridview.

i try to send path to datagridview and succes. here is the code

```
namespace tstIniF
{
    public partial class fmMain : Form
    {
        string ConfigFileName = "app.cfg";

        CFileConfig cFileConfig;

        public fmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cFileConfig = new CFileConfig();

        }



        private void btnQuit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void btnDirectort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dlgFolder.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
            string s = dlgFolder.SelectedPath;
            txtDirectory.Text = s;


            /*p = (string)dgvConfigFile.Rows[idx++].Cells[1].Value; cFileConfig.cfgContourFile = p;
            p = (string)dgvConfigFile.Rows[idx++].Cells[1].Value; cFileConfig.cfgConnectionString = p;*/
        }



        private void btnDirectBase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dlgFile.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
            string s = dlgFile.FileName;
            int idx = 0;
            dgvConfigFile.Rows[idx++].Cells[1].Value = cFileConfig.cfgBaseMapFile = s;
        }

        private void btnDirectCont_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dlgFile.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
            string s = dlgFile.FileName;
            int idx = 1;
            dgvConfigFile.Rows[idx++].Cells[1].Value = cFileConfig.cfgContourFile = s;
        }

        private void btnDirectConn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fConn op = new fConn();

            op.ShowDialog();
        }
}
}
```

red mark as btnDirectConn i show new form like this

[image: Image2]

and here is my form fConn

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace tstIniF
{
    public partial class fConn : Form
    {
        public fConn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtServ.Text.Trim() == "" || txtDb.Text.Trim() == "" || txtUid.Text.Trim() == "" || txtPwd.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Mohon diisi semua field....");
            }
            else
            {
                //string textAll = this.txtServ.Text + this.txtDb.Text + this.txtUid.Text + this.txtPwd.Text;
                fmMain frm = new fmMain();
                frm._textBox = _textBox1;
                this.Close();
                //Close();
                //frm.Show();
            }
        }

        public string _textBox1
        {
            get { return txtServ.Text + txtDb.Text; }
        }
    }
}
```

the question is how to show data in form fConn to fmMain datagridview , i fill the fConn entry and close and back to fmMain so the result is

[image: Image3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use delegate to handle this,

change `fConn`form as below

```
public partial class fConn : Form
{
    public SaveDelegate SaveCallback;

    public fConn()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveCallback("set text what you need to send to main form here...");
    }
}
```

And `fmMain` as below

public delegate void SaveDelegate(string text);

```
public partial class fmMain
{
    public fmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnDirectConn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fConn op = new fConn();

        op.SaveCallback += new SaveDelegate(this.SavemCallback);
        op.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void SavemCallback(string text)
    {
        // you have text from fConn here ....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the frmMain declare the fConn form at the class level so that it won't get disposed when the form closes.  Now the frmMain can access any public objects in fConn.

Don't re-declare frmMain in fConn.  Use `_textBox = op._textBox1` right after `op.ShowDialog();`